# Boxcox Transformation Error - "contains observations that are not strictly positive"

Tags: data-transformation, stata

I am trying to do a Box-Cox transformation for a data set in Stata, using the following code:

boxcox Production_qty price technology gender, model(lambda) notrans(gender)

It gave me an error saying "gender contains observations that are not strictly positive". Can anyone please clarify to me why am I getting this error for the dummy variable?

Comment: Are you trying to imply that you wish to transform a "dummy variable"?  This is an important issue because the effort, in that case, is pointless.

Comment: No, my dependent variable is Production_qty & independent variables are price, technology & gender, where Production_qty, price & technology are not normally distributed. Thus, I tried the above code for the Box-Cox, but getting an error for the gender variable. Do I not need to include gender in the code for the Box-Cox?

Comment: whuber clearly stated that its pointless to transform a dummy (as 0/1 for gender would be). Indeed to transform any other coding of a binary would be pointless. Don't waste your time trying. The reason why you get the error message is because 0 is not positive. As for why Stata is trying to do it anyway, that's presumably a coding issue.